# Probability of number drawing

Tags: probability

The number 1,2,3,4 are written on slips of paper and 2 slips are drawn at random one at a time without replacement.  What is the probability the first number is 2 or the sum is 5?

Answer (score 1):

Let A be the event that the first number is 2, and B be the event that the sum is 5.

Then $P(A  \text{ or }  B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A \text{ and }B)=\frac{1}{4}+\frac{2}{\binom{4}{2}}-\frac{1}{4}\cdot\frac{1}{3}=\frac{1}{4}+\frac{2}{6}-\frac{1}{12}=\frac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

There are $12$ ways to draw two slips one at a time:

- $1,2$
- $1,3$
- $1,4$
- $2,1$
- $2,3$
- $2,4$
- $3,1$
- $3,2$
- $3,4$
- $4,1$
- $4,2$
- $4,3$

There are $6$ ways to do it with the first one being $2$ or the sum being $5$:

- $1,4$
- $2,1$
- $2,3$
- $2,4$
- $3,2$
- $4,1$

**Hence the probability is $\dfrac{6}{12}$**